# How can I change the target-framework in Visual Studio 2010 (unit-Test)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, .net-framework-version

I developed a small webpart. Now I want to create a unit-test for this webpart.
I used this [tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/adebruyn/Visual-Studio-SP1-and-SharePoint-2010-Unit-Test) to create the unit-test. The presenter change the target framework from .Net 4.0 to 3.5, but I can´t change the target framework to 3.5 (I get the following information).

Microsoft Visual Studio: Attempted re-targeting of the project has been canceled. You cannot change the specified .NET framework version or profile for a test project.

So I tested [this](http://msdnrss.thecoderblogs.com/2011/05/retargeting-visual-studio-test-projects-for-net-4-platform-update-1/). Unhappily it doesn´t work.

as Information: If I want create a new test-Project Visual Studio doesn´t show any projects for .NET 3.5 (only 4.0).

How can I change the target framework to 3.5? Are there updates for Visual Studio 2010?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you have VS service pack 1 installed?

Comment: I am not sure. Could it be the Problem?

Comment: Go `Help -> About` and look for the service pack. and yes, it *could* be the problem, i recall having the same problem altho i cant recall how i fixed it.

Comment: Ok - I installed the SP1 - and now it works. thank you :)

Comment: i'll add it as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Visual Studio Service Pack 1. I had this issue and this resolved it for me.